# Convert matrix to cell and replace NaN with '-'

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan, cell-array

I have a matrix `A`

```
A = [nan nan 1 0 nan]
```

How do I convert matrix `A` to cell, and replace `nan` with `'-'`, so a new `B` cell array will look like this:

```
B = {'-' '-' 1 0 '-'}
```

I tried

```
A = mat2cell(A);
```

or

```
A = num2str(A);
```

then

```
A(cellfun(@isNaN,A,'uniformoutput',false)) = {'-'};
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try `num2cell`

```
B = num2cell(A);
B(cellfun(@isnan,B)) = {"_"};
```

which gives

```
>> B
B =
{
  [1,1] = _
  [1,2] = _
  [1,3] =  1
  [1,4] = 0
  [1,5] = _
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your idea using [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) is good, maybe the usage just isn't clear!? You could also use [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html), which seems a bit more easier to use. Additionally, [indexing with logical values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-3)  also works with cell arrays, which might be more efficient than `cellfun` and similar:

```matlab
A = [nan nan 1 0 nan]

B = num2cell(A);
B(isnan(A)) = {'-'}
```

Output:

```
A =
   NaN   NaN     1     0   NaN

B =
{
  [1,1] = -
  [1,2] = -
  [1,3] =  1
  [1,4] = 0
  [1,5] = -
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could pair two of your attempts, note that you *do* want `'UniformOutput'` from the `cellfun` because you need a logical array.

```
A = num2cell(A);
A(cellfun(@isnan,A)) = {'-'};
```

Alternatively you could just use a loop...

```
B = cell( size( A ) );
idx = isnan( A );
for ii = 1:numel(A)
    if idx(ii)
        B{ii} = '-';
    else
        B{ii} = A(ii);
    end
end
```

This might seem obtuse, but if you're struggling with the correct implementation of `mat2cell`/`cellfun`/etc, then you can guarantee code written with those functions will be harder to maintain for yourself and others! At least the loop is explicit, and not necessarily slow these days (although if you're storing numeric data in mixed type cell arrays then I have to assume performance isn't paramount anyway).